# VueJS initially mark first radiobutton as 'checked'

Tags: vue.js, radio-button

How can I  initially mark first radio-button as 'checked'?

```
items =
  [
    {txt: 'foo', val: 1},
    {txt: 'bar', val: 2}
  ]


<div  v-for="item in items">
   <input name="myfield" type="radio" v-bind:value="item.val" v-bind:checked="item.val==comparisonvalue">
   <label>{{ item.txt }}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `v-model` to bind the `input` to your data, in which case set an item (e.g. `myInput`) in your data and then initialize it with the first value in your items array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myInput: 1,
    items:
      [
        {txt: 'foo', val: 1},
        {txt: 'bar', val: 2}
      ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <input 
      name="myfield" 
      type="radio"  
      v-bind:value="item.val"
      v-model="myInput">
    <label>{{ item.txt }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Under most circumstances, you might get the `items` from an API call, and then you can initialize it in `created`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myInput: null,
    items: null
  },
  created () {
    this.items = [
        {txt: 'foo', val: 1},
        {txt: 'bar', val: 2}
      ]   // or from an API call
    this.myInput = this.items[0].val
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <input 
      name="myfield" 
      type="radio"  
      v-bind:value="item.val"
      v-model="myInput">
    <label>{{ item.txt }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or get the `index` in `v-for` and then check whether `index === 0` at the `input`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items:
      [
        {txt: 'foo', val: 1},
        {txt: 'bar', val: 2}
      ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <input 
      name="myfield" 
      type="radio"  
      v-bind:value="item.val" 
      v-bind:checked="index === 0">
    <label>{{ item.txt }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```