# How to select radio button by default, when created /w v-for in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, radio-button, v-for

I am rendering out radio buttons element in vuejs with v-for statement. 
I want the first button to be checked by default.

```
HTML
<div v-for="(course, index) in courses" :key="index">
    <input
        v-model="selectedCourse"
        v-bind:value="course"
        type="radio"
        name="course"
    />
    <label>{{course}}</label>
</div>


JavaScipt
data() {
    return {
        courses: [course1, course2]
    }
}
```

I expect the first radio button to be checked.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365131/vuejs-initially-mark-first-radiobutton-as-checked

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `v-model`, you would have to set the bound data prop to the first item in the `courses` array.

```
this.selectedCourse = this.courses[0];
```

You could also set `selectedCourse` from start, if you know the value of the first item in the `courses` array.

```
data() {
  return {
    courses: ['course1', 'course2'],
    selectedCourse: 'course1'
  };
}
```